# How to perform Java or Qt Like MultiThread Programming in C#

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, qt

You know that multi-thread programming is of  great importance for us to develop  something more efficiently.

And there is  common structure for multi-threading concept in Java, Qt or ACE They provide us a common interface to implement such as `void run()` method, Mutex and Semaphore.

And C# has some kind of multi-thread facilities. But If a developer like me want to use so-called structure,what should he/she do?  There is a any library or something?

Comment: I don't really understand your question... Are you asking which threading APIs .NET provides?

Comment: yes  but this api provide us same structure which java, qt  have

Answer (score 3):

In C# there's [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx), [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx), [Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Parallel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx), [Async Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) and a whole lot of other techniques you can use.

It all depends on the context. "What do you want to do" determines what tools you'd want to use.

**Edit:**
Javas `Runnable` interface can easily be mimiced in C# (examples from [this](http://www.shannonhardt.com/ThreadingInJavaCsharp.pdf) paper):

**Java**:

```
public class Counter implements Runnable { 
  private int count; 
  public Counter(int val) { this.count = val; } 
  public void run() { 
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++) 
    System.out.println(“Hello World”); 
  } 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Counter c = new Counter(10); 
    Thread t = new Thread(c); 
    t.start(); 
  } 
}
```

**C# Equivalent:**

```
using System; 
using System.Threading; 

namespace SimpleThreadExample { 
  class Counter { 
    private int count; 
    public Counter(int val) { this.count = val; } 
    public void DoCount() { 
      for(int i=0; i < count; i++) 
        System.Console.WriteLine(“Hello World”); 
    } 
    [STAThread] 
    static void Main(String[] args) { 
      Counter c = new Counter(10); 
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(c.DoCount)); 
      t.start(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I m used to  implement run method for  threads and i can't find this interface in C# but I think this is common structure and i want to use this structure

Comment: In C# you need to specify which method is the `run` method: See http://www.shannonhardt.com/ThreadingInJavaCsharp.pdf for a comparison between Java and C# regarding threads.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern language packages come with libraries that allow access to the OS calls that manage additional threads inside a process. Pick one and have a go.  Ask again when you have something that you cannot get to work correctly.